# Laravel job, missing parameter

Tags: laravel, jobs

I try to dispatch a job in Laravel.

Job:

```
    public $items;
    public $milestone_delivery_date;
    public $project_id;

    public function __construct($items, $milestone_delivery_date, $project_id)
    {
        $this->items = $items;
        $this->milestone_delivery_date = $milestone_delivery_date;
        $this->project_id = $project_id;
    }
```

PartController:

```
    public function storeImportedParts(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        $milestones = $project->milestones->where('material_delivery', 1);

        $milestone_delivery_date = '';

        if ($milestones->count()) {
            $milestone_delivery_date = $milestones->first()->due_date;
        }

        $items = $request->items;

        $this->dispatch(new StoreImportedParts($items, $milestone_delivery_date, $project));
```

In this case, the following error occurs:

```
[2020-01-31 08:23:16] local.ERROR: Too few arguments to function App\Jobs\StoreImportedParts::__construct(), 0 passed in /xxx/xx/xxx/xxx/app/Jobs/StoreImportedParts.php on line 37 and exactly 3 expected
???
```

If I change the vars with numbers like this, it works:

```
        $this->dispatch(new StoreImportedParts(1, 1,1));
```

Of course, there is an error but the params arrive in the Job:

```
[2020-01-31 08:24:02] local.ERROR: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() {"userId":2,"exception":"[object]
```

In PHPStorm, the display is also different:

[image]

[image]

Why the params do not pass into the Job?

Comment: which one  is Jobs/StoreImportedParts.php line 37?

Comment: the error said that u pass zero parameters, so the error cannot be this line.

Comment: I found it. For tests i implemented ` $this->dispatch(new StoreImportedParts());` in the part controller. Then i copied it into the Job without modification. Sorry!